# After removing category attributes I get errors when reindexing: Undefined offset in Flat.php

Tags: attributes, eav, category-attribute

After removing category attributes I get these errors in the log file when I reindex "Category Flat Data":

> ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 149  in
> [...]\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php on
> line 799
>
> ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 150  in
> [...]\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php on
> line 799

Options *"Use Flat Catalog Category"* and *"Use Flat Catalog Product"* under *System->Config->Catalog* are disabled.
It seems that category attributes were removed correctly (after that operation all works without any problems), I did it this way in the setup file:

```
$setup = $this;
$setup->startSetup();
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_cat_thumbnail1');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_cat_thumbnail2');
$setup->endSetup();
```

And the setup file was configured this way in the module's *config.xml*:

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Example_Mymodule</module>
                    <class>Example_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_setup>
            <mymodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_write>
            <mymodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

I investigated the *Flat.php* file and the line 799 (marked with a comment in the snippet below) is inside this method:

```
/**
 * Return attribute values for given entities and store
 *
 * @param array $entityIds
 * @param integer $store_id
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getAttributeValues($entityIds, $store_id)
{
    if (!is_array($entityIds)) {
        $entityIds = array($entityIds);
    }
    $values = array();

    foreach ($entityIds as $entityId) {
        $values[$entityId] = array();
    }
    $attributes = $this->_getAttributes();
    $attributesType = array(
        'varchar',
        'int',
        'decimal',
        'text',
        'datetime'
    );
    foreach ($attributesType as $type) {
        foreach ($this->_getAttributeTypeValues($type, $entityIds, $store_id) as $row) {
            $values[$row['entity_id']][$attributes[$row['attribute_id']]['attribute_code']] = $row['value']; //THIS IS THE LINE
        }
    }
    return $values;
}
```

On line 799, this part of the code: `$row['attribute_id']` returns 149. The same number is in the error message:

> Undefined offset: 149...

Number 149 is the value of the **attribute_id** column in the `eav_attribute` table in database. So 149 is the ID of the attribute that was already removed. The row with this ID in the `eav_attribute` table doesn't exist anymore (since this attribute was removed). But somehow Magento still tries to get the data of this attribute for some categories.

So this `$row['attribute_id']` returns 149. And when Magento tries to get element 149 from this array: `$attributes[$row['attribute_id']]` it throws error because there is no attribute with ID 149 in `$attributes` array.

It looks like attributes were removed from the `eav_attribute` table, but Magento still stores the data of the removed attributes for some categories. If a category had any data in those removed attributes, that data is still stored in the database.

1. But shouldn't it be removed since I removed the attributes?
2. Or did I remove the attributes incorrectly?

Comment: take a look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26445/146. Maybe you are missing some constraints on the category EAV tables. Normally when an attribute is deleted, the values for that attribute should be deleted also.

Answer (score 5):

The eav_attribute's values are still in the entities value tables (`catalog_category_entity_text`, `catalog_category_entity_int`, etc.) and therefor the flat indexer is giving you issues.

Easiest way to solve this is to install this N98 Magerun addon 
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner and run its `eav:clean:attributes-and-values-without-parent` command.

Afaik there are no foreign key constraints from the `attribute_id` column on the value tables to the `eav_attribute` table, so it doesn't automatically delete them. I'm not sure why..

Comment: EAVCleaner does not support table prefix (yet)

Answer (score 2):

Its seems like you didn't remove your attribute correctly. I just tried the same attributes that you created in my local server. And also I have removed the attributes safely. To remove attribute use the below code,

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_cat_thumbnail1');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_cat_thumbnail2');
```

put this code in some where in file, make sure that file ll execute . or access your store from external file like this,

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_cat_thumbnail1');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_cat_thumbnail2');

echo 'success';
```

And if you want completely remove the attribute (I am saying history), then delete the setup entry in `core_resource` table, and delete also module files that you were put in local or community directory and xml file in `etc/modules`..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. This is exactly what I did, I used this code to remove attributes: `$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_cat_thumbnail1');` where `$installer` is an instance of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`. I edited my question and added the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the ID in error is 187. And you are sure that it needs to be/was removed.

**Step 1.** Open the following tables and check for it. It should not exist.

- `catalog_eav_attribute` and check for existance of `attribute_id = 187`
- `eav_attribute` and check for existance of `attribute_id = 187`

**Step 2.** Then open the following (value) tables `catalog_category_entity_datetime`, `catalog_category_entity_varchar`, `catalog_category_entity_int`, `catalog_category_entity_decimal` and `catalog_category_entity_text`

- Again search for rows with `attribute_id = 187` and delete

**Step 3.** *Answer needs an update to complete*.

Because after re-indexing the `catalog_category_entity_int` values keep being re-created. It is I think coming from the table `catalog_category_entity` where the correct `entity_id`'s also need to be removed. But of this I am not sure.